# Condense three dataframes to one, remove duplicates and nans

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes which look like this:

```
    SA_ID   MTRCYCCD    DA_JAN_2015
0   1234    T           BUNDLED
1   5678    V           BUNDLED
2   2345    D           BUNDLED
3   7891    V           BUNDLED

    SA_ID   MTRCYCCD    DA_JAN_2016
0   1123    T           BUNDLED
1   5678    V           BUNDLED
2   4567    D           BUNDLED
3   7891    V           BUNDLED

    SA_ID   MTRCYCCD    DA_JAN_2017
0   1123    T           BUNDLED
1   5678    V           BUNDLED
2   2123    D           BUNDLED
3   1001    V           DA
```

I want to merge/groupby/whatever to make a single dataframe to look like this:

```
    SA_ID   MTRCYCCD    DA_JAN_2015    DA_JAN_2016    DA_JAN_2017
0   1234    T           BUNDLED        NaN            NaN
1   5678    V           BUNDLED        BUNDLED        BUNDLED        
2   2345    D           BUNDLED        NaN            NaN
3   7891    V           BUNDLED        BUNDLED        NaN
4   1123    T           NaN            BUNDLED        BUNDLED
5   4567    D           NaN            BUNDLED        NaN
6   2123    D           NaN            NaN            BUNDLED
7   1001    V           NaN            NaN            DA
```

I've tried a few things, like:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['SA_ID','MTRCYCCD'],how='outer').merge(df3,on=[SA_ID','MTRCYCCD'],how='outer)
```

and:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='SA_ID',right_on='SA_ID',how='outer').merge(df3,on='SA_ID',how='outer)
```

I think groupby is what I need, but I'm not sure how to get where I want to go.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your first code: pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['SA_ID','MTRCYCCD'],how='outer').merge(df3,on=['SA_ID','MTRCYCCD'],how='outer')
 is working just fine

Comment: It's a duplicate of one of Wen's solutions. You want `reduce(lambda l, r: pd.merge(l,r, on=['SA_ID', 'MTRCYCCD'], how='outer'), [df1, df2, df3])`

Comment: @Vaishali, then am I thinking about this the wrong way, maybe? 

I don't want any "SA_ID" duplicated.  When I check this using 

merged_df['SA_ID'].duplicated(keep=False), I see that some instances are "True"

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here?

Comment: For example, the total number of rows in my merged_df is = 178379.

When I do: len(merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['SA_ID']))

I see that the number of rows is 112789.  So something isn't working.

Comment: Possibly you have duplicate SA_ID to begin with. Pl check for duplicates in all the three dataframes

Comment: @Vaishali ugh, yep. duplicates in the original dfs.

Comment: For completeness, this did the trick:   
merged_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['SA_ID','MTRCYCCD'],how='outer').merge(df3,on=['SA_ID','MTRCYCCD'],how='outer').groupby('SA_ID').first().reset_index()